# PostGIS populating existing table with imported shapefile

Tags: postgis-2.3

I have a PostGIS database with an empty table ch01.highways. With the following code, I want to populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO ch01.highways (gid, feature, name, state, geom) 
SELECT gid, feature, name, state, ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 2163) 
FROM ch01.highways_staging 
WHERE feature LIKE 'Principal Highway%'
```

The ch01.highways_staging table was imported with the shp2pgsql-gui. For both tables, the owner is postgres.

When I run the command the ch01.highways remains empty, no data are imported.

Comment: do you get any error message? did you check, if  there is  data in the `ch01.highways_staging` table?

Comment: no, no error message. yes, I have the data I need in the ch01.highways_staging table. There is also a spatial index for that.

Comment: It is a *huge* mistake to ever load or manipulate data as the primary administrator account,  be it `root`, `SYS`, or `postgres`. You really ought to create a login or three and start over from scratch before you accidently harm the database instance. You haven't provided the result of the `SELECT` statement without the `INSERT`. While creating a spatial index is good procedure, it has nothing to do with a query with no spatial constraint. Please [edit] the question in response to requests for clarification;  it's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for details.

Comment: could you add sample data from that ch01.highways_staging table (screenshot maybe)? do you need to update a potentially populated table or do you just want to create that table like that (for you could do that in one step)?

Comment: what do you mean by adding sample data? I can visualize the ch01.highways_staging table with QGIS

Comment: I extracted a road from ch01.highways_staging and used the command

Comment: INSERT INTO ch01.highways (gid, feature, name, state, geom) 
SELECT gid, feature, name, state, ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 2163) 
FROM ch01.highways_staging_e 
WHERE feature LIKE 'Principal Highway%'  
again. The table remains empty

Comment: Hello Vince, I left the postgres user and work with a user postgis_in_action. Here's the SELECT statement without the INSERT command:

Comment: `SELECT gid, feature, name, state FROM ch01.highways_staging WHERE feature LIKE 'Principal Highway%`

Comment: The query works fine and selects only highways that are Principal Highways.
In the meantime, I wonder if I have a problem with "NULL entries" in the shapefile which I imported as ch01.highways_staging. Does anybody have experience with shapefiles containing "NULL entries"? Thanks a lot!